# Heartbeat package not found.centos

Tags: centos7, high-availability, heartbeat

I tried to install heartbeat on Centos 7 by yum install heartbeat but it's giving me package not found.Does heartbeat (linux-HA) supported in centos 7 or not? .

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.praction.in
 * epel: epel.dionipe.id
 * extras: mirrors.praction.in
 * updates: mirrors.praction.in
No package heartbeat available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heartbeat is considered deprecate since RHEL7 / CentOS7.](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48126)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old and that heartbeat has been deprecated but in some legacy environments it might still be necessary so I have put some packages on the following link:

https://github.com/PranayPallavTripathi/heartbeat-related-packages-for-centos-7

Please note that:

1. to install heartbeat for centos 7 from the packages downloaded from the above link, you also need certain other dependencies like sbd, openhpi, etc. These dependencies are not currently present at the above link so remember to install them separately.
2. the packages heartbeat and heartbeat-libs depend on each other (circular dependency) so if neither is installed currently in your environment then to install them you have to provide their name together to `yum install` command as shown below:

```
yum install heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```